# How to acces to my database in a recyclerview Android?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to update my data with a buttonclick in a recyclerview:
I can display my database in the recyclerview and now I would like to update the marks when i click on a button (Like stackoverflow's system btw).

So, i have made this on my Adapterwomen (for the recyclerview) and I would like to call it when i click a button.

```
public void UpdateData() {
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this)
        String marksafter;
        int marksint = Integer.getInteger(marks.getText().toString());
        marksint = marksint + 1;
        marksafter = Integer.toString(marksint);
        myDb.updateData(id.getText().toString(),marksafter );

    }
```

But "this" gave me an error, what can i replace this with?

Comment: What is the constructor for `DatabaseHelper`? What class is `UpdateData` inside?

Comment: I prefer not to access the DataBase within the RecyclerView or its Adapter. Let know of the parent Activity or Fragment to handle the Database operations.

Comment: @MelvinAuvray which error are you getting? And you should not update the  database from adapter. Instead of that you can have a interface in your adapter which will help you to communicate with your activity or fragment, then using that you should update database in your activity or fragment.

Comment: @pk4393 Where should i update the database so ? Because i want to update the Data "marks" in the specific Holder, Look at the last picture of my post, i want to change the marks independently of the others marks:

Comment: @MelvinAuvray can you share the constructor code of you DatabaseHelper class

Comment: @pk4393 Is that what you wanted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MelvinAuvray as per your constructor of DatabaseHelper class

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}
```

you should pass the Activity reference or Application reference to

```
myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

but you are passing the **ViewHolder reference to it which is wrong.**

And for database design pattern you can follow this article

http://wale.oyediran.me/2015/04/02/android-sqlite-dao-design/

Comment: How can i do so ? Can you give me an example or smthing ? How I can pass The Activity reference or Application reference instead ViewHolder in the ViewHolder ?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't catch it, how can I get my database in my recycler view so ? And if i can't, how can I get around this ?

Comment: @MelvinAuvray you can initialize the DatabaseHelper in your onCreate() method to your activity and then using interface pass the data from adapter to Activity or fragment whenever you perform a click on an Item in, and after getting data to your activity or fragment you should update the data to your database

Comment: awesome trick with excellent design pattern example. hat's off